# ClassNotFoundException HttpRequestInterceptor

Tags: java

I am getting this weird exception on this line:

```
HttpSolrServer server = new  HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/");
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor
    at com.polgar.dipl.index.SolrIndex.init(SolrIndex.java:36)
    at com.polgar.dipl.index.SolrIndex.getInstance(SolrIndex.java:30)
    at com.polgar.dipl.main.ArticleIndexer.main(ArticleIndexer.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: ...and the code around line 36 that causes this error is...?

Comment: Hello @Makoto: the large bold font line ;)

Comment: I don't see a large, bold line.  I see exactly one line of code that does not include HttpRequestInterceptor.

Comment: @jahroy Makoto edited the question so the bold line changed into "one line of code" :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Getting the same problem. We both must be playing with Solr 3.6

I had to download the HttpClient jars from the HttpComponents project. They didn't seem to be included with Solr 3.6

http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

3.6 Has a new version of the client that uses the new HttpComponents (4.0) stuff, not the old HttpClient (3.1) stuff. The old 3.1 jar is there, but not the new one.

Once I copied the jars over, it worked.

I copied the following (not all may be needed).

```
httpclient-4.1.3.jar
httpclient-cache-4.1.3.jar
httpcore-4.1.4.jar
httpmime-4.1.3.jar
```

works for me, now.

Comment: Awesome. I downloaded httpComponents and compiled with maven. Works great.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Maven to include SOLRJ, you'll also want the following phrases in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the HttpClient Jar file in your runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. To resolve this, I have done following:

1. Checked the versions available of http components in your  "~.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents" directory
2. Based on that add following entries in your pom.xml file and rebuild your  project by running `mvn clean install` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command one by one. 
   (If you are behind the proxy, make sure you have provided essential configuration in your settings.xml file)

This should resolve the problem, It did for me. :)

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```