# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams

Tags: android, apk, proguard

When i debug my app it is working fine but when i try to export my apk and install it i am getting this issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams
at aig.a(Unknown Source)
at ahy.q(Unknown Source)
at ahy.d(Unknown Source)
at ahy.r(Unknown Source)
at ahy.c(Unknown Source)
at ahy.a(Unknown Source)
at ahy.a(Unknown Source)
at ahy.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.application.Login.a(Unknown Source)
at com.application.Login.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5115)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using proguard,

I have added reference libs also like this:

```
-libraryjars /libs/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/twitter4j-core-2.1.6.jar
```

any idea..@thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18246887/2624806 can help you here.

Comment: n mostly it can related with wrong lib jar file ur using, check here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10423230/2624806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no HttpCore in your libs.

Please import [HttpCore](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar)

This link is HttpCore 4.1, You can search HttpCore 4.2 or 4.3 if you want.

In the future, when you import a library please ensure that you import the relevant library

Comment: i have used HttpCore in libs and exported too ..seems its not working,,same issue

Comment: I think you should download http components in this link and add to your libs. http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to you `proguard-project.txt` file:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** {
    *;
}
```

I would also suggest you to use [repackaged version of HttpClient for Android](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) instead of original HttpClient jar to avoid class loading collisions with the version bundled with Android. But as far as I can see you'll also need to rebuild Signpost HttpClient module to use `ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib` package instead of `org.apache.http` (and don't forget to update package name in `proguard-project.txt` as well).

Comment: @ldolon i have already added the above class i proguard-project.txt but same issue

Comment: @Janmejoy Have you tried to use repackaged verion of HttpClient I mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Import the package on your bundle

```
Import-Package: org.apache.http.params
```

Answer (score 1):

In the standard Android builds (Ant, Eclipse, Gradle), don't specify -libraryjars or -injars, since the build scripts will already specify those for you. Just make sure you add all necessary library jars to the libs directory, as usual, so the build scripts will include them.

In Eclipse, libraries may need to be marked as Exported.